# Why does WordPress strip custom HTML that are form elements and theme SVG icons?

Tags: filters

When I add a custom HTML block that only includes form elements e.g. form, input, textarea, etc, WordPress appears to be stripping these wholesale.

Similarly, if I add a SVG icon that is part of a theme e.g. GeneratePress, WordPress appears to also remove this.

Why is WordPress filtering these and what solutions/options do I have?

Comment: Why? Security.  Options?  Augment the array that WP uses to filter (via wp_kses functions) them out of content.  These should help: https://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/201762/add-html-tags-to-the-allowed-tags-list-in-wordpress  *and*  https://wp-mix.com/wordpress-basic-allowed-html-wp_kses/

Comment: @jdm2112 - Thanks. I figured as much although shouldn't these be permitted/allow based on a role and/or capability? Or if I've misunderstood, doesn't this have the potential of breaking Gutenberg block plugins that include a libraries of SVG icons for example or form plugins?

Comment: the tags you can insert into post content are limited for security reasons for most users, if you want to insert forms and embeds you should embed them via OEmbed or use shortcodes/custom blocks to insert arbitrary HTML. The HTML block isn't a way to put any HTML in a post, it just gives you the opportunity to insert HTML that's valid in a post that you've constructed yourself. Some administrators on some sites have the `unfiltered_html` capability which bypasses this, but this carries major security problems and is not advised (and would get stripped out if a non-admin updated it )

Comment: @TomJNowell - Do you mean that if I wish to add a custom form I've crafted, I should be creating a block for it? If yes, that's for effort than value since it takes me 5 minutes to create a valid HTML5 form that posts data to an external API. It seems that if I don't use wp_kses_allowed_html, it strips out content from themes and plugins. For instance, with some themes, there is an option to add SVG icons from a predefined library they include. When adding these, it strips it out when saved. I would thought filters such as these would have a significant impact on themes and plugins.

Comment: a block, a widget, a shortcode, oembed, etc etc, but not by copy pasting form and input tags into the posts content. And no, it does not have that impact because those filters are applied to the post content, not the rendered content. `wp_kses_post` will strip out script tags etc, but it does not strip out `[shortcode]` or other things, that stuff gets converted _after_ the security pass through. Also those filters happen on save, not on render.

Comment: Also `add_shortcode` isn't too difficult: `add_shortcode( 'yourform', 'name_of_a_function_that_returns_your_html_as_a_string' )`? There are lots of ways to put a form in a page or post, putting _raw_ HTML with form tags scripts inputs etc is near the bottom of the list when it comes to safety security and practicality, even though it might be super convenient to you

Comment: As for the themes and SVGs I think there's more going on there than you've been lead to believe, it's extremely unlikely that raw SVG markup is being inserted into the post content, it is both safer and easier for the theme developers to do it via a shortcode, especially if they have a predefined library to select from. Even allowing SVGs to be uploaded to the media library would be easier via a copy paste filter or a plugin that can sanitise SVGs and enables them such as Safe SVG. Anyway the TLDR is you cannot do what you tried to do, what you want is possible but that is not how you do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is WordPress filtering these

Because it's a major security hole. WordPress sanitises your posts content to a whitelist of tags and attributes on save. When the posts content is displayed additional filters ( `the_content` ) are used to convert features into their final markup. E.g. by swapping out shortcodes, rendering dynamic blocks, taking OEmbed URLs and swapping them out for their embed HTML codes, etc.

The exception is in non-multisite self-installs where the administrator may have the `unfiltered_html` capability. This is a very dangerous capability that bypasses the security, e.g. you can insert unbalanced tags that cripple your site, or bitcoin miners and malware. Also anybody who isn't an admin that opens this post and saves will strip it all out.

> and what solutions/options do I have?

Literally any API other than what you did:

- custom shortcodes
- filters
- templates
- custom blocks
- custom widgets ( or even the custom HTML widget )

But not raw form html and javascript executing in the posts content.

The easiest is probably a shortcode, e.g. `shortcode-plugin.php`:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: I'm a plugin yay
 */

add_shortcode( 'yourshortcode', function( $atts ) : string {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <form>
        ....
    </form>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, ideas and example. If a shortcode is the easiest solution, why is the HTML block available?

Comment: as I said in the comments further up, the HTML block does not do what you think it does. It is not a _raw_ unprocessed HTML block that lets you insert anything you want. Blocks have HTML output, and that output gets processed by filters, this block lets you control what that HTML output is, but that doesn't mean it doesn't get processed by filters. Your expectations for the HTML block os inaccurate, it only behaves the way you expected it to behave when a user has the `unfiltered_html` capability, and there is no method of making an exception just for that block.

Comment: e.g. if I wanted to insert a paragraph with a particular arrangement of tags and attributes I could do that with the custom HTML block, perhaps this would let me insert a shortcode in a tag attribute, or maybe I prefer to type my tags out manually? Or maybe I'm a super admin with the `unfiltered_html` capability? There are lots of reasons I might want a custom HTML block that don't involve using forbidden/dangerous tags, some of which are purely personal preference, some people like writing HTML instead of WYSIWYG.

Comment: The same is also true of the classic editor, anybody could have gone to the text view and inserted form and script tags, but unless they had `unfiltered_html` it would get stripped out on save. That doesn't meant the text view was only for adding form/script tags, lots of people used it for other things even with the filtering. The HTML block is the equivalent of that text view without the constraints of having to conform the markup to match block validation

Comment: Excellent answer, as always Tom.  This is the WordPress way.